# Seeking Software Solution to Recreate a 90s CRT TV Experience for My Vintage TV Shows

Tags: open-source, video

I'm in search of a software solution that can help me replicate the nostalgic experience of using a CRT TV from the 90s. Specifically, I want to emulate the ability to scroll through channels using a remote control, but in this case, I'd like to cycle through my own collection of TV shows from the 80s and 90s.

Currently, I have a VCR connected to my CRT TV, and I'd like to set it up so that it continuously plays different TV shows on various "channels" without manual intervention. Essentially, I want to relive the feeling of stumbling upon different programs while flipping through channels on an old CRT TV.

Is there any software available that can help me achieve this nostalgic setup? Any recommendations or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your mention of VCR implies that your collection hasn't been digitized. Once digitized most of the Linux Media Center software like Kodi have skins available and are able to create custom channels of content.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I appreciate your suggestion to digitize a few of my VHS tapes, especially the rare ones. However, I'm quite attached to the idea of authentic experience of inserting a VHS tape into a VCR, so I'll be using the VCR for some of the tapes. Also, thank you for pointing out that KODI can create custom video channels; I wasn't aware of this feature. I'll definitely explore it further.